# Bootstrap specifics with weighted outcome estimation

Tags: bootstrap, weighted-data

I am using bootstrapping to estimate the standard error of a weighted estimate.  The process to calculate the estimate is:

1. Sample from the population
2. Calculate a weight for each individual based on their and other individual's covariates (the goal is to have the sample marginal covariates better resemble those in another population)
3. Calculate the weighted outcome

My question is at which point should the bootstrap resampling occur?  Between (1) and (2) or between (2) and (3)?  I.e. do we sample individuals and then recalculate their weights?  or do we resample from individuals with their fixed weights attached?

My intuition is that it should be the former; with bootstrapping we are trying to mimic the process of resampling from the population, and if we were able to do that, upon each resampling an individual's calculate weight would differ, because the sample marginal covariates would differ.  Consequently, we need to recalculate weights at each bootstrap repetition.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: What are these weights and why are you using them? Give us some context.

Comment: There some information in (2) and as a top line summary all I can do is repeat that: the goal is to weight individuals so the sample marginal covariates resemble those of a different population (i.e. the mean height and weight of the sample is the same as the mean height/weight in a different population).  These weights are then applied to the outcome so the weighted outcome from our sample is comparable to the outcome in the other population.  The method is know as matching adjusted indirect comparison, or MAIC.